# @ServiceActivator How to read inputChannel from property file in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

i develop google pubsub consumer and when i use fix value "my-alpha-pubsub-topic" it's complete running

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-alpha-pubsub-topic" )
 public void messageReceiver(String payload) {
  LOGGER.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload);

 }
```

But i run it on Container in Kubernetes i need pass inputChannel value from env parameter by Environment for 1 container build support multiple environment

```
Alpha => inputChannel = "my-alpha-pubsub-topic"
Staging => inputChannel = "my-staging-pubsub-topic"
Production => inputChannel = "my-pubsub-topic"
```

Buy i cannot pass parameter in inputChannel. it's run failed

```
@Value("${pubsub.name}")
 private String pubsubName;


@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "${pubsubName}" )
 public void messageReceiver(String payload) {
  LOGGER.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload);

 }
```

and i Try this and Failed

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "${pubsubName}" ) 
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "#{${pubsubName}}" )
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "${pubsub.name}" )
```

How i can pass value to inputChannel from properties or env parameter

Comment: `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "${pubsub.name}" )` should work. What does the exception say?

Comment: @Vladucu
Parameter 0 of method messageChannelAdapter in net.trueid.platform.cmschange.MyGcpSubPlanetApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="${pubsub.name}")

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
 - User-defined bean method 'myInputChannel' in 'MyGcpSubPlanetApplication'
 - User-defined bean
 - User-defined bean

Comment: Ok, I realized where the problem is. You can't use `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "${pubsub.name}" )` since the `inputChannel` needs to receive the qualifier of a spring bean not an env variable. I suppose that somewhere in your code you have a channel with the qualifier `my-alpha-pubsub-topic` and that is why it worked for the first time. Maybe it will make sense to create all those beans using spring profiles and have something like this: `@Profile("Staging")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-staging-pubsub-topic" )
 public void messageReceiver`. One for each env.

Comment: @Vladucu Voican That solve my problem. You can answer and I will accept your answer

Comment: Glad to hear that, I will add it in a minute. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use
`@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "${pubsub.name}" )` since the **inputChannel** needs to specify the qualifier of a spring bean not an environment variable.
I suppose that somewhere in your code you have a channel with the qualifier **my-alpha-pubsub-topic** and that is why it worked for the first time.

For my point of view it will make more sense to create all those beans using spring profiles and have something like the following for each environment

```
 @Profile("Staging") 
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "my-staging-pubsub-topic" ) 
 public void messageReceiver(String payload) {
    LOGGER.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload);
 }
```